# PostgreSQL : Query to retrieve informations about fk on a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, querying

I want to retrieve these informations from PostgreSQL for one table name :

For each foreign key, the name of the field corresponding to the fk, and the name of the table witch is referenced by.

Can I do it with sql query ?
Thanks for help

Comment: Hmm but I have one problem : my table constraint_column_usage is empty..

Comment: Well, you should at least provide the exact version you're using then.

Comment: If the usual solution doesn't work, please provide more detail. `SELECT version()`, the SQL used to create the table(s), and the SQL used to query the `information_schema`.